# Login into twitter from personal website

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter, twitter-oauth, social-media

I wish to create a login for my website using Twitter. I wish to let the user type his **Twitter Handle** inside a textbox and once he enters I need to validate it by making an API call to Twitter and confirm that and need to display the **Twitter name** of the user and his **twitter profile pic**. Is this possible using plain JavaScript to implemet this feature? As Twitter is using **OAuth** for authentication now, can this be implemented with only JS? Kindly, pass on any links if you know. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: May google "twitter oauth api javascript"...

Comment: @Jonasw I did but it does not serve my purpose. I need to fetchg the details using just <b> Twitter Handle </b>.

Answer (score 0):

After some research, I cam across this amazing node based API, **twit**, whcih can be installed just by saying ***npm install twit***.
You can also get the details on https://github.com/ttezel/twit.

Best part of this plugin is, it takes care of all the authorization with Twitter and gives you a set of methods.

**Code example :**

```
var twit = require('twit');
      var T = new twit(config_parameters); // contains you access tokens;
      T.get('users/show', { screen_name: twitterHandleName},
                            function(err, data, response) {
                                console.log(data);      
                           });
      });
```

It has many utility methods that help to resolve your queries that you require from **Twitter**